# How to display Json nested objects (maps) in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, object

I am new to flutter, I want to display json nested objects "nom" values (So I can later on create a tabBar using these values).
I am getting this error

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
```

This is [the json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY3d4.png) I am working on

This is the main code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'tabbarclass.dart';

Future<stations> fetchDonnee() async {
  print('fetch0');
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('uri'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('fecth1');
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
    return stations.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
   else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class MyApp3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp3> {
  
  late Future<stations> futureDonnee;
Timer? timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initstate');
    futureDonnee=fetchDonnee();
    timer= Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds:1), (Timer t){
      futureDonnee=fetchDonnee();
      setState(() {});
      print('initstate1');}
    );
    print('hi1');
    super.initState();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    print('builder');
    FutureBuilder f1;
    print('ok');
         Center(  
          child: 
          f1=FutureBuilder<stations>( 
            future: futureDonnee, 
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print(snapshot.data!.comp);
                //snapshot.data!.comp.forEach((k, v) => print(k));
                return Scaffold( 
                  body:  Container(
                        width: size.width,
                        height: 85,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 20),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration( 
                        color: Colors.white 
                        ),

                        child: Text('${snapshot.data!.ond}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13)),
                      )
                );  
              } 
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');}
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          )
         );
     return f1;     
  } 
}
```

This is the class I defined

```
class stations {
  final Map ond;
  final Map comp;
  final Map gaz;
  final Map eau;
  final Map nom;

  const stations({     
    required this.ond,
    required this.comp,
    required this.eau,     
    required this.gaz,
    required this.nom, 
    });

  factory stations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>json) {
    return stations( 
      ond: json['ond'],
      comp: json['comp'],
      eau: json['eau'],
      gaz: json['gaz'],
      nom: json['nom'], 
    );
  }
}
```

And this is [the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tcbc.png) I am getting

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Trying adding your response initialization `futureDonnee=fetchDonnee()` to setState.

Comment: try to use this https://app.quicktype.io/ to build your model class its a tool to convert Json to dart class and other language

Comment: use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ to generate model from json, try print value of your variable and runtimeType before error